# How can I compare two lists with specific key in dict in python

Tags: python

I want to take two lists with dict value and find the specific values that appear only in first list.

In this case, only compare 'name' key.

```
a = [
       {'name': 'joseph', 'age': 33}, 
       {'name': 'Emma', 'age': 11}, 
       {'name': 'apple', 'age': 44}
    ]
b = [ 
       {'name': 'apple', 'age': 44}, 
       {'name': 'Emma', 'age': 22}
    ]
```

`returnOnlyOne(a, b)` 
would return `[{'name': 'joseph', 'age': 33}]`, for instance.

The `set()` solution is not for this case.

Answer (score 1):

For efficiency, we first make a `set` of the names in `b`, then [filter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) the list `a`:

```
from operator import itemgetter

def returnOnlyOne(a, b):
    b_names = set(map(itemgetter('name'), b))
    only_in_a = list(filter(lambda item: item['name'] not in b_names, a))
    return only_in_a
```

Sample output:

```
a = [
       {'name': 'joseph', 'age': 33}, 
       {'name': 'Emma', 'age': 11}, 
       {'name': 'apple', 'age': 44}
    ]
b = [ 
       {'name': 'apple', 'age': 44}, 
       {'name': 'Emma', 'age': 22}
    ]

print(returnOnlyOne(a, b))
# [{'name': 'joseph', 'age': 33}]
```

If you don't like `itemgetter`, `filter` and the like, you can write the same using comprehensions:

```
def returnOnlyOne(a, b):
    b_names = set(item['name'] for item in b)
    return [ item for item in a if item['name'] not in b_names]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `list` comprehension with `map`. (BTW, what's inside your `list` is called `dict`):

```
[d for d in a if d.get('name') not in list(map(lambda x:x.get('name'), b))]
# [{'age': 33, 'name': 'joseph'}]
```

Explanation:

- `list(map(lambda x:x.get('name'), b))`: gets all *name* from `b`
- `d.get('name') not in`: checks if *name* from `a` doesn't exist in `b`. (i.e. appear only in first list)

Answer (score 0):

Nearly the same as the others.

```
print([ item for item in a if item['name'] not in set(item['name'] for item in b)])
```